# Flip matrix across its diagonal

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

What would be the simplest way to reorder my number values in the second matrix with 90 being in the top left and 10 being in the bottom right? My brain is going blank and I know there has to be any easy way to go about this. Any help is appreciated tremendously!

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: screenshot]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main() {
    cout << "Before:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            int matrix[9][9] = {

            { 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 },
            { 19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,},
            { 28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36 },
            { 37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45 },
            { 46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54 },
            { 55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63 },
            { 64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72 },
            { 73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81 },
            { 82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90 }
            };
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }



    cout << "After:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            int transMatrix[9][9] = {

            { 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 },
            { 19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,},
            { 28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36 },
            { 37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45 },
            { 46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54 },
            { 55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63 },
            { 64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72 },
            { 73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81 },
            { 82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90 }
            };
            cout << transMatrix[j][i] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: std::transform will definitely do the job

Comment: @Ian Copenhaver As for me then I have not understood the question.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I think that Ian wants to mirror the matrix diagonally

Comment: I’ve fixed the title and description based on my understanding of the question (and my attempt to read the blurry text in the screenshot thumbnail).

Answer (score 2):

You could just loop in reverese.

```
for (int i = 8; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 8; j >= 0; j--) {
        //Print element [j][i] here
    }
}
```

Also move the matrix assignment to outside of the loop as pointed out by [Federico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca)

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the following matrix

```
#define ROW 3
#define COL 4

int main()
{
    int mat [ROW][COL] = {
                            {1,  2,  3,  4},
                            {5,  6,  7,  8},
                            {9, 10, 11, 12}
                         };
    //...

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### 1/ If you want the backwards matrix

```
int backwards_mat[ROW][COL];
for(size_t i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < COL; ++j)
    {
        backwards_mat[i][j] = mat[ROW-1-i][COL-1-j];
    }
}
```

#### 2/ If you want the transposed matrix

```
int transposed_mat[COL][ROW]; //swap the dimensions
for(size_t i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)
{
    for(size_t j = 0; j < COL; ++j)
    {
        transposed_mat[j][i] = mat[i][j];
    }
}
```

---

If you prints the two matrices, the backwards will be:

> 12 11 10 9 
>   8 7 6 5 
>   4 3 2 1

And the transposed will be:

> 1 5 9 
>   2 6 10 
>   3 7 11 
>   4 8 12

---

You should be able to easily apply this to your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the following?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 9;
    int matrix[N][N] = 
    {
        { 10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 },
        { 19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,},
        { 28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36 },
        { 37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45 },
        { 46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54 },
        { 55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63 },
        { 64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72 },
        { 73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81 },
        { 82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90 }
    };

    for ( const auto &row : matrix )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row ) std::cout << item << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }            

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N - i - 1; j++ ) std::swap( matrix[i][j], matrix[N-j-1][N-i-1] );
    }

    for ( const auto &row : matrix )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row ) std::cout << item << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }            

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 
37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 
46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 
55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 
64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 
73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 
82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 

90 81 72 63 54 45 36 27 18 
89 80 71 62 53 44 35 26 17 
88 79 70 61 52 43 34 25 16 
87 78 69 60 51 42 33 24 15 
86 77 68 59 50 41 32 23 14 
85 76 67 58 49 40 31 22 13 
84 75 66 57 48 39 30 21 12 
83 74 65 56 47 38 29 20 11 
82 73 64 55 46 37 28 19 10
```